# Upgrading kernel on Debian server hosting Xen 3.2.1

Tags: xen, kernel, debian-squeeze

I have a physical server running Debian 6 and Xen Hypervisor 3.2.1, and `kernal -a` says "2.6.26-1-xen-amd64".  I have not updated for a long time, because when I run `apt-get upgrade`, one of the updates is linux-image-2.6-amd64.  My understanding was that my kernel needs to have Xen support, will upgrading to this kernel break my dom0?

I have myself up against a wall, because I host a VM for a website that isn't mine, so I need the latest security updates, but can't risk taking them offline. Eventually they will move off, and I won't be hosting something I am unqualified to host, but that isn't the point right now.

Comment: Please post your kernel- and initrd-lines of your current grub configuration for your Dom0.

Comment: @Nils - I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I do not know about Debian 6, but on SLES grub is the bootloader.
If you look into the configuration, you will see that xen is loaded instead of the usual kernel, and the usual kernel is passed as parameter to xen. So the kernel-version might be independent from your xen-version.

Comment: I know I am using GRUB, but I guess it is configured quite differently from SLES.  Running `uname -a` I get "Linux foo.bar.com 2.6.26-1-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 13 21:39:38 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux".